# How can I wp_send_json data?

Tags: ajax, json

I'm building an AJAX'd process where I need to queue a few ajax calls, but I need, on each step's success, to send, from my back-end, what the next step is.

I have 4 functions, all of which were registered through the `wp_ajax_XX` hook and an internal array of the structure:

```
'step-1' => ['callback' => object, 'done' => True];
'step-2' => ['callback' => object, 'done' => False];
```

And an internal function that checks which step I'm on, what is next and if it can proceed. I would like to be able to send, when `step-1` finishes, a `json_success` item to my JS, signaling that, indeed, the back-end is done with `step-1` and it can proceed to `step-2`. **The problem is...**

I need to let my JS know about what exactly to call. My JS would get back the exact endpoint it needs to hit from `step-1`, because `step-2` might be dynamic.

In short, how can I send data through `wp_send_json`?

(Currently, you can only send a string response and `wp_send_json_success` doesn't seem to work)

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding the problem as you describe it, and the snippet you posted doesn't appear to be PHP or JS. Some code would go a long way

Answer (score 1):

It seems `wp_send_json_success` works! I just did something very wrong with it.

When you hit the AJAX endpoint, at the end of the logic, simply:

```
wp_send_json_success( ['next_step' => 'enpoint_2'], 200 );
```

This will send an object to JS:

```
Object{next_step: 'endpoint_2'}
```

Which you can then use to further your process.